# Can we Assign Javascript variable value to Razor Syntax Variable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can we Assign Javascript variable value to Razor Syntax Variable?

like.

```
  var Javascript-variable=$("#test").val();

  @html.Actionlink("User","Index",new {Id='Javascript-variable'})
```

Comment: Please provide your code and expand your question with what have you tried

Comment: Write your question title to google...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we Passing Java script variable value to Razor Syntax Variable?

No, because JavaScript used in this context executes on the client, whereas Razor code executes on the server. For practical purposes, they have no relation.

But I imagine that you want to use the routing capabilities provided on the server from within JavaScript, and that is possible. We can use Razor to generate JavaScript.

- Embed the `ActionLink()` call into a JavaScript snippet.
- Render the URL structure on the server, using the `ActionLink()` method which is route-aware.
- Get a value on the client.
- Insert the value into the URL structure.

One way to do that is to render the link with a placeholder value, which is later replaced using JavaScript.

```
var url = '@Html.ActionLink("User","Index",new { Id = 0 })'; 
var id = $("#test").val();
var mergedUrl = url.replace(/0$/, id); // replace the 0 with a real ID
```